# I cannot verify client's access token when I containerize my resource server

Tags: spring-boot, docker, oauth-2.0

I come to you today to ask you about this problem that I am having with my Docker container.
Indeed I protected my rest API resource with OAuth2 as indicated by the pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

this is application properties config

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://authServer.com/auth/realms/api-dev
```

My authorisation server is keycloak and is deployed in a Docker container
when I start my resource without docker everything is correct and I can authenticate clients accesstoken and access the resource protect without problem.
But when I containerize my server resource I receive a 401 error as a return on my postman client and the docker container log is as follows

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://authServer.com/auth/realms/api-dev/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://authServer.com/auth/realms/api-dev/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:169) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:97) ~[spring-security-oauth2-resource-server-5.7.4.jar!/:5.7.4]
        ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://authServer.com/auth/realms/api-dev/protocol/openid-connect/certs": Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Indeed I was trying to protect my resource and give authorisation only to those who have a valid access token

Comment: Probably, the host is not recognized, try with ip address instead of `authServer.com`

Comment: Thank you @birca123 for your proposal, the result is the same, no change. However,  when I run **wget -S https://IP:8443/auth/realms/api-dev/.well-known/openid-configuration** in my container I obtain this result 
**wget: can't connect to remote host (IP): Operation timed out**

Comment: This is clearly a network problem between your two containers. Either DNS or firewall issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to check that the signature of JWT is valid, Spring Security needs to acquire the certificate defined by the configuration option

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer
```

through the cert OIDC endpoint defined by the Keycloak's realm configuration.

When you use different docker containers for Keycloak and Resource Server, you should ensure that one container can interact with the other on the network level. You can find many tutorials that describe how to implement network availability between containers in details just pick the one where you can use names instead of IP addresses.